# Add text with specific height to pdf TCPDF

Tags: php, laravel, tcpdf

I'm having trouble getting some text to be added to a pdf in te correct measurement with TCPDF. This is the function I'm writing for adding a cell with text.

In this particular example I have called it like this: `addText($pdf, '10', 150)` meaning it will write "10" 150mm high.

I calculate a factor between a set fontsize (10) and the desire height (150 in this case). When I set the new font size based on the factor and measure the height again it's 150.

I also set padding and margin to 0 in the cell. But still the text comes out smaller (while the cell is the correct size). I don't think it's because of padding. If I set the cell to 300 mm high the text is till around 80 high.

I tried all kinds of combination for the three alignment options in the cell, which just moves the text around but keeps it at this magical ca.80 height.

Any ideas? How do I make the cell show the text in the actual set size. Or alternatively make the text enlarge until it runs out of vertical space in the cell.

```
private function addText(TCPDF $pdf, string $text, int $desiredHeightInMm, int $posX = 0, int $posY = 0, array $textColor = [0, 0, 0], string $fontFamily = 'myriadpro'): void
{
    $initialFontSize = 10;
    $pdf->SetFont($fontFamily, '', $initialFontSize);

    $initialHeight = $pdf->getStringHeight(0, $text);   
    $scalingFactor = $desiredHeightInMm/ $initialHeight;
    
    $newFontSize = $initialFontSize * $scalingFactor;
    $pdf->SetFont($fontFamily, '', $newFontSize, '', false, 'UTF-8');
    
    // If I do $pdf->getStringHeight(0, $text) here it will tell me that the text is 150mm high. So the factor is correct

    $pdf->SetTextColor($textColor[0], $textColor[1], $textColor[2]);
    $pdf->setCellPadding(0);
    $pdf->setCellMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    $pdf->SetXY($posX, $posY);

    $pdf->Cell(150, $desiredHeightInMm, $text,  1, 0, 'C', false, '', 0, true, 'T', 'C');      
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are trying to adjust the font size to ensure that the text you are adding to the PDF matches the desired height in millimeters. However, there are some issues with the way you are calculating and setting the font size.

Try this:

```
private function addText(TCPDF $pdf, string $text, int $desiredHeightInMm, int $posX = 0, int $posY = 0, array $textColor = [0, 0, 0], string $fontFamily = 'myriadpro'): void
{
    $pdf->SetFont($fontFamily, '', $desiredHeightInMm); // Set font size directly based on desired height.

    $pdf->SetTextColor($textColor[0], $textColor[1], $textColor[2]);
    $pdf->setCellPadding(0);
    $pdf->setCellMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    $pdf->SetXY($posX, $posY);

    $pdf->Cell(0, $desiredHeightInMm, $text, 0, 0, 'C', false, '', 0, true, 'T', 'C');
}
```

Instead of calculating a scaling factor and setting the font size, directly set the font size to the desired height ($desiredHeightInMm). This ensures that the text will be the desired height in millimeters.

In the Cell method, set the cell width to 0. This makes the cell width automatically adjust to the text content, which is useful for ensuring that the text is not truncated.

By directly setting the font size to the desired height and letting the cell width adjust automatically, you should achieve the desired text height in millimeters without any scaling issues.

Comment: That doesn't work since font size is points, not mm's. So with this solution the text ends up even smaller.

Comment: you can convert millimeters to points using the standard conversion factor (1 inch = 72 points).